# Removing arrays from np.split() array results

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to remove specific sections of an array using `np.split()`.

I was attempting to use a more complex loop to remove the sections because the number of split sections is not constant and changes often.

I have an array of consecutive numbers, an array of ordered cut locations, and knowledge of which cut locations need to be removed.

Ex.

```py
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
cut_array = [3,6,10,13]
```

Desired output.

```py
result = [[1,2,3],[7,8,9,10],[14,15]]
```

So the idea is to remove the part of the array between each set of 2 elements in the cut_array.

Edit: the location of the cut array may be at the beginning or end of the starting array

Comment: When you say the cut could be at the start or end, are you saying that `cut_array` could include the first or last indices?

Comment: One way or other you have to know what each "pair" of `cut_array` elements means.  Since you are working with lists, you don't gain any 'speed' by avoiding an iteration.

Comment: yes, the index in cut_array can be the first or last value in the original array a, so the array section to be removed is not always every other array starting from index 1. Also the loop is unrelated to this process, This seperation of arrays has to be done to ~350 more initial arrays 'a' in a loop

Answer (score 1):

With `np.split` and slicing:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15])
res = np.split(a, cut_array))[::2]
```

---

```
[array([1, 2, 3]), array([ 7,  8,  9, 10]), array([14, 15])]
```

Comment: the problem is I am not sure if slices are always in the middle or if they also occur at the beginning/end.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious way of cutting sublists from a list is:

```
In [299]: alist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]; cuts = [3,6,10,13]
In [300]: [alist[:3],alist[6:10],alist[13:]]
Out[300]: [[1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9, 10], [14, 15]]
```

to do this for a variable size `cuts`, first pad that list, as needed, to handle the end slices:

```
In [301]: cuts = [None,*cuts,None]
In [302]: cuts
Out[302]: [None, 3, 6, 10, 13, None]
```

and then use a list comprehension, with `zip`, to use successive pairs:

```
In [303]: [alist[i:j] for i,j in zip(cuts[::2],cuts[1::2])]
Out[303]: [[1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9, 10], [14, 15]]
```

`np.split` iterates on its cuts, returning a list of array slices.  So there's no speed benefit in avoid a list or list comprehension.

Working from an array:

```
In [304]: arr= np.array(alist)
In [305]: [arr[i:j] for i,j in zip(cuts[::2],cuts[1::2])]
Out[305]: [array([1, 2, 3]), array([ 7,  8,  9, 10]), array([14, 15])]
```

alternatively, making all cuts, and selecting every other (as shown in the other answer with split):

```
In [306]: [alist[cuts[i]:cuts[i+1]] for i in range(len(cuts)-1)]
Out[306]: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13], [14, 15]]
In [307]: [alist[cuts[i]:cuts[i+1]] for i in range(len(cuts)-1)][::2]
Out[307]: [[1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9, 10], [14, 15]]
```